# Getting JavaScript's global variable initialized in a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the value of a global variable by declaring it at the constructor and then initializing it with a value in a function. What I am trying is quite similar to the code which I have typed here. The code executes but nothing gets printed. Can someone tell me what is happening?

```
class Sample{
  constructor(){
    let joey ="";
  }

  fire(){
    joey ="Yo";
    console.log(joey);
  }
}
```

Comment: does joey belongs to global or the sample class of the constructor? How are you calling printing it (calling the method?)

Answer (score 3):

use "this" keywords for declare a global variable in constructor.

```
class Sample{
 constructor(){
    this.joey ="";
 }

 fire(){
    this.joey ="Yo";
    console.log(this.joey);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with classes, use "this" operator and assign values to "this" object as scope of "let joey" is not global(read "let" scoping) the way you defined it. See below -

```
class Sample{
 constructor(){
    this.joey ="";
 }

 fire(){
    this.joey ="Yo";
    console.log(this.joey);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `joey` is not contained within the scope of `fire`.

When you create an object (in this case an instance of the class `Sample`) you can set the properties of that object using the `this` object as it  is a reference to the current object. If you use `let`or`var` the variable will be contained to the function it is declared in (in this case `constructor`).

```js
class Sample{
 constructor(){
  this.joey ="";
 }

 fire(){
   this.joey ="Yo";
   console.log(this.joey);

 }
}
let test = new Sample();
test.fire();
```